# How find sum of values in array of objects with specific distinct value pair?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to find sum of values in an  array of objects with specific user and create a different array of objects with total value for the particular user.

This is the Array of objects that I have.

```
var userData = [
  {name: "user1", amount: 80},
  {name: "user1", amount: 12},
  {name: "user1", amount: 8},
  {name: "user2", amount: 60},
  {name: "user2", amount: 12},
  {name: "user3", amount: 90},
  {name: "user3", amount: 28}
]
```

The out put that I need.

```
UserGrandTotal = [
  {name: "user1", totalamount: 100},
  {name: "user2", totalamount: 72},
  {name: "user3", totalamount: 118}  
]
```

Comment: Please provide the JavaScript that you have tried as a [mcve]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `reduce` method for this by passing a `callback` provided *function* which is applied for every item in the array.

I created an `hash` structure using `reduce` where I stored every unique `name` as *hash* `key` and, as *hash* value, we have `user` details with total `amount` for that specified `user`.

As *complexity* of the *algorithm*, we have `O(N)` because we're iterating the whole array only once.

```js
var userData = [ {name: "user1", amount: 80}, {name: "user1", amount: 12}, {name: "user1", amount: 8}, {name: "user2", amount: 60}, {name: "user2", amount: 12}, {name: "user3", amount: 90}, {name: "user3", amount: 28} ]; 

var result = Object.values(userData.reduce((hash, item) => {
    if (!hash[item.name]) {
        hash[item.name] = { name: item.name, amount: 0 };
    }
    hash[item.name].amount += item.amount;
    return hash;
}, {}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you use reduce and push the result to a separate variable instead of using a foreach?

Comment: @Thefourthbird, I updated my answer with a simple hash structure.

Comment: Yes, forEach could be another option, but using `reduce` we don't need to declare an optional variable `result = []`.

Comment: Also, with `reduce` we can use a shorter way with `comma operator` : `var result = Object.values(userData.reduce((hash, item) => (!hash[item.name] ? (hash[item.name] = { name: item.name, amount: item.amount }) : (hash[item.name].amount += item.amount), hash), {}));`

Answer (score 2):

To give alternative answer using `forEach` and `find`:

```js
var userData = [
  {name: "user1", amount: 80},
  {name: "user1", amount: 12},
  {name: "user1", amount: 8},
  {name: "user2", amount: 60},
  {name: "user2", amount: 12},
  {name: "user3", amount: 90},
  {name: "user3", amount: 28}
]

let userGrandTotal = [];

userData.forEach(user => {
  let grandUser = userGrandTotal.find(userGrand => userGrand.name === user.name);
  if(grandUser) {
    grandUser.amount += user.amount;
  }
  else {
    userGrandTotal.push(user)
  }
})

console.log(userGrandTotal)
```